# Firebase user phone number verification

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can see that Firebase has phone number authentication but all I want is just to verify the phone number. I do not want to sign in using the phone number. Can I achieve this or should I use other service for sms verification?

Comment: You can. Just go through the process of getting the PhoneAuthCredential from onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential). I think that is enough, but my code 'linkWithCredential()'s just to make sure which is basically what Frank is saying with regards to leaving the user signed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verifying the phone number is part of signing the user in to Firebase Authentication. You cannot use Firebase phone number authentication without signing the user in to Firebase Authentication.

That said: there are many situations where you can likely leave the user signed in to Firebase without problems.

Comment: Does this mean that even when a user is signed in with one of the other methods and I want to verify their phone number I have to sign them in again using the phone number auth? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @gasho I was wondering the same thing. Did you find out if you have to sign a user in again?

Comment: Yes they will. Phone number authentication is a separate provider in Firebase Authentication, and you sign into each provider separately. Mind you: you can implement the flow for this however you like: so a single form that asks for email+password+phone could be all the user sees, and then you sign them into both email+password and phone provider behind the scenes and link them together.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the answer, I never received a notif that you responded, I just happened to check just now. For my app I use only email to sign the user in, once inside to access other parts of the app they must verify their phone which means I sign them in again (behind the scenes) after they receive the sms. Now that I signed them in with phone credential, does that somehow invalidate their email sign in? If they change their # do I have to sign them in again (behind the scenes)? Once they sign out and sign back in via email, do I have to pull their # and sign them in again?

Comment: Btw once they get the sms, I store the phone # in their uid node and also in keychain. If they logout and login I pull their number from the node then set in keychain. When it’s time to access other parts of the app I use keychain for verification.

Comment: If the phone number and email+password accounts are linked, signing in with one gives you access to the information about the user from both providers. So you have to sign in with only one. Note that there are way too many questions here for me to answer. You might have better luck of you post a separate question, but there too: limit to one question per post please.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Later today I’ll post everything as questions and add some code for clarity. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can just use this

```
import React from "react";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import firebase from "firebase";
import './firebaseui-styling.global.css';

const config = {
  // your firebase config
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);



const PhoneVerification = () => {

    const uiConfig = {
        signInFlow: 'popup',
        signInOptions: [
            {
                provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                recaptchaParameters: {
                    type: 'image',
                    size: 'invisible',
                    badge: 'bottomleft'
                },
                defaultCountry: '+91',
                whitelistedCountries: ['IN', '+91']
            }
        ],
        // callbacks: {
        //     signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
        //         var no = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential
        //         console.log(no)
        //     }
        // }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
        </div >
    )
}

export default PhoneVerification
```