# is there a way to use firebase verify phone number without authenticate using the number?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

is there a way to verify phone number without authenticate using firebase??

i tried this on init state of sms screen verification

```
_verifyPhone() async{
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: widget.phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        print("yes yes");
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        print(e.message);
      },
      codeSent: (String verficationID, int resendToken) {
         setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verficationID;
          });
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
        setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
      },
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 120)
    );
  }
```

```
 ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Verify', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),),
            onPressed: () async{
              print("pressed");
              if(_verificationCode == textController.text)
              print("yes"); // plus navigate to home screen
              else
              print("no"); // resend or something im trying
             }
          ),
```

i tried the above code but no sms sent to me.
is that because i didnt turn on the phone number authenticate option in firebase?

but i dont want to authenticate using phone Number

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to use firebase verify phone number without authenticate using the number?

No, this is not possible. Firebase's phone number verification is part of the authentication flow, and not a feature outside of that.

> i tried the above code but no sms sent to me. is that because i didnt turn on the phone number authenticate option in firebase?

Phone number verification will indeed not work when phone number authentication is turned off on the project.

Also see:

- [Firebase user phone number verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862844/firebase-user-phone-number-verification/44862926#44862926)
- [How to implement phone number verification in flutter using firebase? (Not Authentication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568503/how-to-implement-phone-number-verification-in-flutter-using-firebase-not-authe/55575973#55575973)
- [How to add or update phone_number in Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625492/how-to-add-or-update-phone-number-in-firebase-auth/59630858#59630858)